# One more "Unable to start service Intent - not found"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Lots of questions about this. But all of them are about "I forgot to add service to manifest" or "I added service not in application tag in manifest". For me there are no such mistakes but still "not found" is given.

My manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PrefActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Preferences" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".ExampleService"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

Me starting service (from main activity's fragment):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.save_btn: {
            getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), ExampleService.class));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Service code, for "just in case":

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {

    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Log.i("LOG_TAG", "service started!");
    }

    private void fireNotification() {

        // prepare notification with icon and text
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Notification text",
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        // prepare action for notification pressed
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // prepare extended notification's info (when notification bar opened)
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Title", "Notification text, baby!", pendingIntent);

        // clear notification after pressing:
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // fire the notification!
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        fireNotification();
        Log.i("LOG_TAG", "notification fired!");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried fully qualifying package in intent (when specifying ExampleService.class) and in manifest - not helping.

When I press that button - service not started. LogCat shows:

```
342-352/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.drobiazko.den.iremember/.ExampleService }: not found
```

Comment: What _is_ the package name of your Service?

Comment: ExampleService.java: package com.drobiazko.den.iremember;  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.drobiazko.den.iremember" >

Comment: try using com.drobiazko.den.iremember.PrefActivity in your manifest, and check if that is the class route.

Comment: Not sure I got your recomendation right, but I tried `getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PrefActivity.class));` instead of `getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), ExampleService.class));` and it worked great. Why won't that work for starting a service? ((

Comment: Why did you specified `android:enabled="false"` in your manifest? It clearly disables your service.

Comment: That's a lol. I totally misunderstood this attribute's meaning from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html. You can post that as an answer.
I'm so good at stumbling upon simpliest difficulties...

Answer (score 0):

**Try This 1**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExampleService.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

**and in your Manifest file**

```
<activity
    android:name=".ExampleService"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Comment: AndroidStudio argues: "... MainActivity is not an enclosing class."

Comment: This is not a answer, is a recomendation.

Comment: Dear Den, I think you are not in MainActivity class, you have to replace MainActivity.this class with the class you are working on.